A question about $W$-trick of density of value

There is a trick, namely passing to a subprogression of common difference $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times \cdots \times w(N)$ for appropriate $w(N)$, which allows one to consider the primes as a set of density essentially $\log \log N/\log N$ rather than $1/\log N$; we will use a variant of this “$W$-trick” later in this paper to eliminate local irregularities arising from small divisors.

The above is quoted from The primes contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions by Ben Green and Terence Tao. My question is: how is this density of value $\log \log N/\log N$ calculated?
I wonder if there are any enthusiastic mathematicians out there who can tell me the source or how to prove it.

The discussion at https://rjlipton.com/2013/01/26/making-primes-more-random/ should help. It also comes up at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/ams-lecture-structure-and-randomness-in-the-prime-numbers/

Have you had a look at those links?

@GerryMyerson Thank you very much, I thought no one had replied. I didn't have time to read them carefully, but thank you. There's a bit too much stuff and I need to take my time to digest the details.
